# My Django Form insert data from the url but it does not if i use it from a modal bootstrap windows

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, django-forms

I spent 2 hours reading answers about forms and modal windows...but i can't figure it out a more abstract issue.

**This are the facts:**

- I have a Django Form working correctly if i access it from the myForm.html's url. I means, the form's data is correctly store in my Heroku's database.
- I have a bootstrap modal window that load correctly my form with the href tag pointing to my form's view.

**This is the problem:**

- If i use my form from my bootstrap modal windows, the form does not insert in the data base.

So, i'm wandering, it's posible to use modal bootstrap windows with form *without add nothing more*?? or it is absolutly need add js o jquery code? In that case... *any suggestion*?

Thanks